# onPause() called before onResume() in BaseActivity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

I have 2 activites A and B. Both of them extend BaseActivity. Activity A is the launcher activity. From A when I click a button, it goes to Activity B. But I found something weird and I don't know if it is normal. According to the activity lifecycle, onResume() is called before onPause(). But when I am on Activity B, the baseActivity first pauses and then resumes. Not only that as I press the back button and reach Activity A, the baseActivity pauses, resumes and then destroys. I still can't understand why. Maybe this is a noob question but I'm curious and I couldn't find any answers online. Hope you guys can help me!

Comment: Kindly ensure: I guess, onPaused was of first activity and OnResume was of Second activity.

Comment: No, I put a log in the onPause and onResume of BaseActivity

Answer (score 1):

I think the onPause came from you first activity and then the OnResume is form the second ... But since they both extends from your BaseActivity you will probably see your base activity events from that order but they are different instances of your BaseActivity

Just to be clear, you have two activities

ActivityA -> BaseActivity

ActivityB -> BaseActivity

If you Log you BaseActivity you will catch events from both activities because they are different instances of BaseActivity and not the same

Comment: So you mean to say along with with onPause  and onResume of the baseActivity, the  onPause  and onResume of Activity A and B are also called?

Comment: Well ... not really .. but almost ... Activity A and B are extensions of the BaseActivity so , the evens onPause and onResume of the ActivityA and B will also be called the baseActivity ones (But in different objects)

Comment: That's managed from Android ... if you come from ActivityA to B , if ActivityA is no longer used by anyone (No one is referencing it), Android will be free to destroy it at any time if he requires the memory or something like that

Comment: But A is never destroyed. B is destroyed and that too everytime. I know it is upto android to destroy it when it has less resources or memory.

Comment: usually activity A is just stopped if activity B is started, but there are many reasons why it could be destroyed (memory usage, back stack flags, etc..). Are you pressing back button? Then android assumes you are done with B and destroys it.

Comment: In activity B i have overridden the onBAckpress() to start activity A  with an intent, so the activity B is paused and not destroyed

Comment: are you calling super.onBackPress() ?

Comment: No, I am starting activity A with startActivity() in the onBAckPress()

Comment: oh sorry, that was my fault, actua;;y I'm calling finish() too!. My bad.

Comment: But this there any way I can use single instance of baseActivity for all these purposes? So that once it is resumed it stays that way?

Comment: No , thats simply not how object oriented works ... you have inheritance which you use in this case to share common behaviors between two instances of different objects (ActivityA and B) if you want them to be completly different just don't make them extend from the same BaseActivity